# Can I use a PostgreSQL/PostGIS function in a "INSERT" code in psycopg2 (Python)?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, postgis, psycopg2

I want to do a INSERT operator in Python using psycopg2 module.

The code is:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tb_places (id_street, geom, number, name, first_year, source, id_user, date) VALUES 
(22, ST_GeomFromText("POINT(-518.944 -2698.2069)", 4326), 34, TEST_1, 1950, Almanak96, 6, 2017-08-01)')
```

When I use concatenation, to generate the INSERT string, it works, however I know that is a bad idea. So I'm trying to use a other alternative to avoid SQL injection.

I tried it:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tb_places (id_street, geom, number, name, first_year, source, id_user, date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', 
[22, "ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-518.944 -2698.2069)', 4326)", 34, 'TEST_1', 1931, 'Almanak96', 6, '2017-08-01'])
```

But I get this error:

```
psycopg2.InternalError: parse error - invalid geometry
LINE 1: ...e, first_year, source, id_user, date) VALUES (22, 'ST_GeomFr...
                                                             ^
HINT:  "ST" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
```

Basically the problem is that I can't pass a SQL function in a string when I want to insert something.

Someone knows what I can do?

Comment: How did the first query even work? Show us the concatenation version not filled values. What is `ST_GeomFromText()`? Is that a Python or Postgres method? Even if Postgres, Python would have erred out as unable to find the function.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest:

```
cursor.execute('''
    insert into tb_places (
        id_street, geom, number, name, first_year, source, id_user, date
    ) values (%s, ST_GeomFromText(%s, 4326), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    ''', 
    [22, 'point(-518.944, -2698.2069)', 34, 'TEST_1', 1931, 'Almanak96', 6, '2017-08-01']
)
```

Comment: How to insert multiple rows at once using ST_GeomFromText?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ST_GeomFromText is a function you created, try

```
geomFromText = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-518.944 -2698.2069)', 4326) # assign value to var

query = """INSERT INTO tb_places (id_street, geom, number, name, first_year, source, id_user, date) VALUES 
(22, %s, 34, TEST_1, 1950, Almanak96, 6, 2017-08-01)""" % (geomFromText) # make it part of query string

cursor.execute(query) # execute
```